# How can hide name when sending through Js

Tags: javascript, php

> I am sending Data like this way But On anchor Hover Its showIng the
>   table name how can i hide the table name and access this name in that
>   function :

```
<a href='javascript:item(1,'name');'> </a>
```

> $list->table_name This showing the Table name on the hover of anchor
>   how can i hide and access the same name in that Item function.

Comment: can u update the code ??

Comment: see this - https://paste.ee/p/72DRP

Comment: Mittul At TechnoBrave@ thanx...

Comment: welcome mam .. check the below solution as well .. this also very useful and proper way I think.

Comment: No its Working Fine M really Glad With Ur Answer..  Thanx @Mittul At TechnoBrave for Quick Response

Comment: my pleasure .. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attribute. This will hide it on hover but it will be on the `DOM`.

`<a href='javascript:item(".$list->id.");' data-table-name='\"".$list->table_name."\"'> </a>`

the output should be like this (*when `$list->id` = 1 and `$list->table_name` = my_table*):

`<a href='javascript:item("1");' data-table-name='my_table'> </a>`

Then you can access it using `JavaScript` [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)
 function.

**Ex:**

```js
var e = document.getElementById('some-id'),
    tableName = e.getAttribute('data-table-name');
    
console.log(tableName); // my_table
```

```html
<a id="some-id" href='javascript:item("1");' data-table-name='my_table'> </a>
```